# DeleteButton triggers "Incorrect Element"

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm implementing an asp.net core API with admin-on-rest.
A custom REST client communicates to the API endpoints, but the mapping is fairly standard.

When I try to implement a  into the interface, the deletion of elements works fine. Still, I get an error on every edit or deletion view for an element with the following text: "Incorrect Element". The console is empty, and everything works as expected.

What causes the error - and how can I solve this?

I've attached a screenshot of the error popup.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uukmx.png)

Update 1:
Here is the code of my custom REST client: [customrestclient gist](https://gist.github.com/sportluffi/ae7b67110579253d275479cc1752e397) and the included fetch.js: [fetch.js](https://gist.github.com/sportluffi/8714ce0a54e747ae4bda4e1fc904fa0d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue. One of my API endpoints returned a list instead of a single element for one of my ReferenceInput-elements.

This was the content response before my change:

```
[{
    "languageId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Danish",
    "isoCode": "dan"
}]
```

And this is the correct response, that does not trigger the error:

```
{
    "languageId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Danish",
    "isoCode": "dan"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check your custom `restClient` returns at least the `id` of the deleted resource inside a `data` object.

Comment: I checked the return. It does return an ID - when the deletion is completed. The error shows up when I open up the edit page, before the actual deletion is happening - but only if if the resource has `remove={Delete}` assigned.

Comment: Why are you trying to open the edit page of an element you are removing ?

Comment: I might have made a vague description. Sorry for that!
The issue only occurs on resources where the remove-attribute is implemented. Once I open an edit or deletion page for this resource, the error message occurs.

Comment: So far I have found out, that the node_modules/admin-on-rest/lib/sideEffect/saga/crudResponse.js is responsible for this behaviour. It looks like `payload.data.Id` is set to undefined although the `payload.data` is not empty and contains an ID - thus triggering the behaviour by having `payload.data.id (undefined) != requestPayload.id (2)`.

I've attached a screenshot of the console, showing that the id is not empty [here](https://imgur.com/a/ojO1E). Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you have a custom restClient ? If you do, can you post it here ?